# Using default values in arguments in marginsize command

Tags: spacing, formatting

I am using the `resume` document class to write my resume.

Since I want to make my resume fit in one page, I would like to decrease the spacing at the top of the document but keep the bottom, right and left margin spacings to the default value.

Googling around, I found that the following lines added at the top of the document

```
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{<top>}{<bottom>}{<left>}{<right>}
```

should do the trick. However, I want to change only the top margin values and keep
the bottom, left and right margins the same. How do I specify the default values to 
the marginsize command for the < bottom >, < left > and < right > fields? A simple example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard package for making margin changes is the `geometry` package.

You can indicate the change by the options in the `geometry` package. If you only want to change the top margin of the document to 0.5 inches, you would use the command

```
\usepackage[top=0.5in]{geometry}
```

Alternatively, if you would like to indicate the margin as a separate command, use the `\geometry` command as follows:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.5in}
```